# 403 Forbidden proxy.github.io when go get some public package

Tags: go, proxy, http-status-code-403

$ go get github.com/jung-kurt/gofpdf
go get: module github.com/jung-kurt/gofpdf: reading https://proxy.github.io/github.com/jung-kurt/gofpdf/@v/list: 403 Forbidden

Answer (score 1):

Check your `GOPROXY` environment variable.

For modules, since [Go 1.13](https://proxy.golang.org/), it should be `proxy.golang.org,direct`, not `proxy.github.io`.

The [OP Ralph Eichelberger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15259306/ralph-eichelberger) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68979953/403-forbidden-proxy-github-io-when-go-get-some-public-package/68980005#comment121954995_68980005) it is working, after a fresh re-installation of Go.

Comment: yes, thank you - I found in a different - working - installation following entry in go env:
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"

I don't know where the wrong came from anyway. Maybe it was set by a older version of go, because I installed go from ubuntu packages and snap also, but finally installed it from tar ball.

Comment: @RalphEichelberger Great! I have updated my answer accordingly.